# assign colors to geom_polygons where fill = discrete category

Tags: r, ggplot2, openstreetmap

I'm struggling to assign colors to my polygons and have tried a host of different approaches but consistently get `"Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale"`.

My code:

```
basemap <- openmap(c(51.5082180,-0.1429767),c(51.5176930,-0.1181475),
                    zoom=NULL,"stamen-terrain")
           basemap_bng<-openproj(basemap, projection=BNG)

 autoplot(basemap_bng) + 
  geom_point(data=BWEe_points, aes(Long,Lat, colour=cluster, fill=cluster)) + 
  geom_polygon(data = chulls_bWE, aes(Long,Lat, group=cluster, fill= cluster), alpha = 0.5)
```

[image: MY RESULT - How can I adjust the color of my polygons?]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read [How to make a great reproducible example in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) to make your question more likely to get an answer. Also you may want to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [how to ask?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: what are the classes of  BWEe_points$cluster and chulls_bWE$cluster ?

Comment: Based on your legend, `cluster` looks like it is numbers instead of categories.  Try `fill = factor(cluster)`.